# How will MariaDB react when I try to perform several big operations (UPDATE/READ) on a table at the same time?

Tags: database, mariadb, heidisql

I have a **MariaDB** and a **Windows Service** accessing this DB. For maintenance, I use **HeidiSQL**.

I now want to update a big table (8.000.000 entries) in HeidiSQL by inserting a new foreign key column and then filling the column with values using `UPDATE`. I suppose it may take about 30 minutes.

During this time, if a user wants to insert/read/delete values out of this table via the service, what will happen? Will the DB block the request? Should I stop the service to avoid corruption of data?

Comment: Chunking the `UPDATE` may help:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: @RickJames, you mean the delete will perform faster when chunked?

Comment: Overall time _may_ be slower, but the interference with other things is likely to be less.  Also, 8M rows may timeout; chunking will prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example myself. The database seems to respond with the old values or status as long as the operations changing the data are still running in HeidiSQL.

What I tried:

- I added a new column. While the adding process was still running I
  sent a read message to my service. It responded without sending the
  new column. As soon as the operation was finished, the new column has been sent, too.
- I filled the new FK column with values. While the updating was
  running I sent a read message. The service gave back the initial
  values of the FK column (0) for all the rows. After the operation was
  finished, the service would sent all the new values.